# Probabilty that a document is relevant than the other base on number of keyword

Tags: statistics, probability

I have 2 documents X and Y. If a user searches for the word "Computer" and I want to display the most relevant document base on the keyword "Computer". My algorithm chooses the most relevant document base on the number of time the keyword appears in the document. The only problem is document X has 10 words with the word "Computer" appearing twice while document Y has 1000 words with the word "Computer" appearing 100 times. It is not right to say that document Y is more relevant than document X looking at the number of words in them.

How do I normalize this to get the most accurate relevant document.

Comment: Just posted an answer. What language are you working in? If it's a language I know, I'll suggested a library.

Comment: The language I'm using is php.

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing is using cosine similarity between your search query and the documents. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity

**Cosine similarity**

The standard for evaluating cosine similarity for text is to create a sparse vector for each the query and document. The vectors represents term counts for the query and document. For simplicity, I'll use python dict notation for sparse vectors.

```
query = {"computer":1}
document = {"the":1, "computer":1, "was":1, ...} # 100 in total.
```

Then you need to compute:

```
cosine_similarity = dot(query, document) / (norm(query) * norm(document))
```

In the example, we can evaluate the dot product by multiplying the values of common terms, and we can evaluate the norms of the query and document using the root sum of squares. Below is an example of how it is calculated.

The dot product is the sum of the product of the values for common occurrences of words in both vectors.

```
# Computer is the only common term, otherwise we would add the products
dot(query, document) = query['computer'] * document['computer'] = 1

norm(query) = sqrt(sum(value**2 for value in query.values())) = 1
norm(document) sqrt(sum(value**2 for value in query.values())) = 10

cosine_similarity(query, document) = dot(query, document) 
                          / (norm(query) * norm(document)) = 0.1
```

Another issue you will likely encounter is some words are more common than others. This will make matching their terms less useful. For this reason, many applications uses [tf-idf weights](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf) instead of simple term counts for cosine similarity. This will multiply the term counts by their relative rarity `log(1/frequency)` instead of using the raw values.

Also, you can find many good implementations of cosine similarity and tf-idf, one is in scikit-learn. http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/metrics.html Since you have a search specific problem, you may want to consider lucene which implements cosine similarity as well.

**Jaccard similarity**

There is one other metric you may consider is the jaccard similarity. It is simpler to understand, but often less effective than cosine similarity. Jaccard similarity is defined as the number of words in both documents divided by the number of words in either document. In math terms, the intersection divided by the union.

Comment: Thanks David. My problem isn't really search specific. I am looking at generalisation and ranking as a whole. Another good example is in case where I have student grouped into teams and have each team rank themselve in a survey. I choose the best performer in each team by taking everyone who came first in the team survey. Being a ranking in the first place makes it bias. Now taking the people at the top of the rank for each team makes it  inaccurate reason because the teams do not have equal number of people. In this case what would be the best approach to take the top performer in each team?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure I understand the team analogy, but if you follow the cosine similarity logic, it is effectively dividing the number of matches by the (geometric) mean of of the number of terms in the two documents. For ranking documents based on relevance to a given term cosine similarity is the most common metric used, as it is normalized to prevent large documents from getting a boosted score simply due to their size.

Comment: btw. I added jaccard as an alternative since it is generally easier to understand and easier to implement if you are not using a prepackaged implementation. It however often does not work as well as cosine similarity with tf-idf .